# NormalDistribution: Problem

Tags: probability

Question:Cans of regular Coke are labeled as containing $12 \mbox{ oz}$. 
 Statistics students weighted the content of 6 randomly chosen cans, and found the mean weight to be $12.11$. 
 Assume that cans of Coke are filled so that the actual amounts are normally distributed with a mean of $12.00 \mbox{ oz}$ and a standard deviation of $0.13 \mbox{ oz}$. Find the probability that a sample of 6 cans will have a mean amount of at least $12.11 \mbox{ oz}$.

I think the answer should be : $(z-μ)$/$σ$ = $(12.11-12)/0.13$ = $0.846$,which $z=.7995$ What I did worng? Can someone help me? Thank!

Comment: Let's say $X$ is normal with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.  Then $P(X<x) = P(Z < \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma})$, where $Z$ is the standard normal random variable.

Comment: I do not engage in your answer the number of cans. Isn't that suspicious?

Comment: I recognize this problem. Did you encounter this problem in a textbook or from an online homework platform? And if the latter, was it by chance a free open-source platform? I'm just curious.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find $z$ that corresponds to the *sample mean* from this exercise. So first a comment on your notation - it should be:

$$z=\frac{\bar{x}-\mu_{\bar{x}}}{\sigma_{\bar{x}}}$$

Of course $\mu_{\bar{x}}=\mu$. But $\sigma_{\bar{x}}\neq\sigma$, as you have computed with. Look up the standard deviation of the sample mean. (Since this is homework I won't give everything away.)

The $z$ that you have computed corresponds to choosing a *single can* that would weigh $12.11$. While that has a certain likelihood associated to it, it would be more rare to find the *mean of 6 cans* to be that far from $12.00$.

Comment: can you give more hint? So,the standard deviation of the sample mean should be(12.11-12)^2? How I should put the 6 in? Should I divide (12.11-12)^2 to 6?

Comment: No, that's not at all how to find the standard deviation of the sample mean. If from individual to individual, $x$ varies with standard deviation $\sigma$, then from sample to sample, $\bar{x}$ varies with standard deviation $\sigma_{\bar{x}}=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$.